# Expressjs app, using websockets for chat. Use different port for websocket server?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, port

I'm making an app using node.js' express framework which serves both html content over http and uses websockets for a chat feature. I'm wondering how I can accomplish both at the same time. My idea is to use a different port for websocket connections (so http requests would come to port 3000 and websockets would connect on port 3001) but I don't know if that's a good solution. I'm especially worried about deployment to something like heroku and if I can specify different ports for my app.

Comment: The only way to do this is to define different ports. I would really recommend making two different 'apps' for this, that can rely on one another. You can run the services at the same time using `node foreman`.

Comment: There really is little reason to use a separate port for webSocket connections.  The webSocket protocol is specifically designed so it can easily share a port with your web server.  The way that this works is that all webSocket connections start with an http request with a couple specific headers set on the request.  That allows your core web server to tell which incoming connections are regular web server requests and which are a request to establish a webSocket connection.  You don't need two servers on two ports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering how I can accomplish both at the same time.

The webSocket protocol is specially designed so it can run on the same port as your regular web server requests.  So, you don't need a separate port in order to have both a web server and chat running using webSockets.

This works because a webSocket connection is always initiated with an http request that sets a few special headers.  The receiving web server can then detect those special headers and know that this incoming http request is actually a request to initiate a webSocket connection.  With a particular response, the client and server then agree to "upgrade" the connection and switch to the webSocket protocol.  From that point on, that particular TCP connection uses the webSocket protocol.

Meanwhile any incoming http request that does not have the special webSocket headers on it is treated by your web server as just a regular http request.  In this way, the same server and the same port can be used for both webSocket connections and regular http requests.  No second port is needed.

Another advantage of this scheme is that the client can avoid the cross-origin issues that it would run into if it was trying to use a different port than the web page it was loaded from.

---

> I'm especially worried about deployment to something like heroku and
>   if I can specify different ports for my app.

If you were to actually use two ports, then you would need to create two separate servers, one listening on each port since a given server can only listen on one port.  In node.js, the two servers could both be in the same node.js app (making it easier to share data between them) or you could put them in completely separate node.js processes (your choice).

And, if you used multiple ports, you'd also have to support CORS so that the browser would be allowed to connect to the separate port (to avoid same-origin restrictions).

Comment: Do you have a code example of this? I have the same use case.

Comment: @Karric - Any server-side webSocket or socket.io library will show you an example of how to hook it into your existing web server.  For example, this page https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ shows how to do it with socket.io.  [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#external-https-server) shows how to do it with the webSocket library.